# Stored Proc Query Timming Out in .net but not sql server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have the following query and its timing out in .net but executing fine in sql server does .net not like temp tables or something ??? I run it in .net and i get a timeout error I dont understand what is going on at all.

```
     SET DATEFORMAT dmy
        declare @AbsenceReasonRestrictions varchar(500)
      set @AbsenceReasonRestrictions ='1'
      create table #absence
    ( 
        record_id INT,
        emp_no int,    
        staff_no varchar(max),
        emp_name varchar(max),
        details text,
        leave_reason int,
        leave_reason_desc varchar(30),
        current_status int,
        date_added datetime,
        dept int,
        dept_desc varchar(100),
        location int,
        location_desc varchar(100),
        division int,
        division_desc varchar(100),
        emptype int,
        emptype_desc varchar(100),
        contype int,
        contype_desc varchar(100),
        conclass int,
        conclass_desc varchar(100),
        line_manager int,
        line_manager_name varchar(510)
    )

        INSERT INTO #absence (record_id, 
            emp_no,    
            staff_no,
            emp_name,
            details,
            leave_reason,
            leave_reason_desc,
            current_status,
            date_added,
            dept,
            dept_desc,
            location,
            location_desc,
            division,
            division_desc,
            emptype,
            emptype_desc,
            contype,
            contype_desc,
            conclass,
            conclass_desc,
            line_manager,
            line_manager_name)

        select ua.record_id,
                ua.emp_no,
                e.staff_no,
                rtrim(e.surname)+', '+rtrim(e.forename1),
                ua.details,
                ua.absence_reason,
                ar.desc_,
                ua.current_status,
                ua.date_added,
                c.dept,
                rtrim(dept.desc_),
                c.location,
                rtrim(loc.desc_),
                c.division,
                rtrim(div.desc_),
                c.emptype,
                rtrim(emptype.desc_),
                c.type,
                rtrim(contype.desc_),
                c.classification,
                rtrim(conclass.desc_),
                ua.manager_user_id,
                (select rtrim(e.surname) + ', ' + rtrim(e.forename1) as emp_name from employee e 
                inner join userlist_mss um on e.emp_no = um.pams_id 
                where um.record_id = ua.manager_user_id)

            from ess_absence_requests ua
                inner join employee e on e.emp_no=ua.emp_no
                inner join absreas ar on ar.code=ua.absence_reason
                inner join contract c on ua.emp_no = c.emp_no
                join dept on c.dept=dept.code
                join location loc on c.location=loc.code
                join division div on c.division=div.code
                join emptype on c.emptype=emptype.code
                join contype on c.type=contype.code
                join conclass on c.classification=conclass.code
                where e.emp_no like '%'
                AND c.main_contract=1
                AND ua.current_status in (1,2,3,4)      
                AND (dbo.fn_XmlElementDateValue(ua.details, 'start_date') >='1/10/2013')
                AND (dbo.fn_XmlElementDateValue(ua.details, 'end_date') <='31/10/2013')
                AND e.active_leaver like 'ACTIVE'
                AND e.emp_no like '%'
                and c.dept like '%'
                and c.location like '%'
                and c.division like '%'
                and c.emptype like '%'
                and c.classification like '%'
                and c.type like '%'
                and ua.emp_no in (select employee_id from userlist_mss_employee_access_rights where manager_id=2)

                order by (dbo.fn_XmlElementDateValue(ua.details, 'start_date'))

             if @AbsenceReasonRestrictions!=''
        begin
            set @AbsenceReasonRestrictions=','+@AbsenceReasonRestrictions+','
            delete #absence where charindex(','+cast(leave_reason as varchar(10))+',', @AbsenceReasonRestrictions) = 0
        end

    select record_id,
        emp_no,    
        staff_no,
        emp_name,
        details,
        leave_reason,
        leave_reason_desc,
        current_status,
        date_added,
        dept_desc,
        location_desc,
        division_desc,
        emptype_desc,
        contype_desc,
        conclass_desc,
        line_manager,
        line_manager_name from #absence

    drop table #absence

    select * from emp_anal
```

Comment: what is your connection string?

Comment: <add name="Server" myConnectionString="Data Source=WIN2008R2PAMS\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True" sysdbfConnectionString="Data Source=WIN2008R2PAMS\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=pamssysdbfHughes;Integrated Security=True" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that management studio has no timeout limit for your query, but when you run it within .net code you are limited connection timeout. Try to change the timeout directly in you connection string or in connection initialization place.

More info:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx
- [Changing SqlConnection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108565/c-sharp-changing-sqlconnection-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

I guess  it's because your direct sql call (using management studio?) uses a different query plan than your .net code ... and the plan .net uses seems to be no good ...

to resolve this try updating table statistics (**update statistics** ) for the tables used by your join and **dbcc freeproccache** to clear the cached query plans ...

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this

Comment: I would recommend to just open a new query in management studio, type the sql commands and execute them ... commands would be "update statistics ess_absence_requests", "update statistics ..." for the other tables in the join and "dbcc freeproccache"

Comment: I thought when you said it is "executing fine in sql server" you mean that it finishes in less than 30 seconds ...

Comment: No it takes long time to execute I no the problem is to do with the 5s