# Dapper QueryFirst Too slow if no connection

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper

it takes almost up to 30 seconds, mostly 20ish avg

```
    public OperadorViewModel GetById(int id)
    {
        IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        var query = @"SELECT 
                          * 
                      FROM 
                        Operadores
                      WHERE Id= @id";

        return con.QueryFirstOrDefault<OperadorViewModel>(query, new { id = id });
    }
```

Is there a way to make it faster to detect there is no connection so i can show error message to user fast instead waiting 30 seconds?...

Comment: You could try opening the connect first to make sure you can connect before executing your query.

Comment: tried and it took 40s+ instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value of [`SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8) property to some lower value.

> Gets the time to wait while trying to establish a connection before terminating the attempt and generating an error.

This way, if there is no connection, timeout will expire earlier and exception will be thrown earlier.

This can also be done through [Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20142746/5779732) or [SqlCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10108565/5779732).